# I lose my bootstrap styles when passing variable (get) to route->Controller->View in Laravel 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, styles

I am integrating a Bootstrap template to laravel 4 and I am having an issue when passing variables through the GET method. My final View renders without any style applied.

Let's say I have a link like this:

```
<a href="{{url('offer')}}">Oferta 2015</a>
```

caught by a route like this>

```
Route::get('offer','HomeController@showOffer');
```

And the controller like:

```
public function showOffer()
{
    $Cursos = Curso::paginate(10);
    return View::make('cursos.offer')->with('cursos',$Cursos);
}
```

That works just fine (the master view extended by the offer view renders perfectly).

My issue happens when I try to pass a variable like this>

link:`<a href="{{url('offer/2015')}}">Oferta 2015</a>`

route: `Route::get('offer/2015',array('myYear'=>'year','uses'=>'HomeController@showOffer'));`

What happens here is that I get the View displayed, but with no styles at all. Just like when you get rid of the "link href ..." in the header.

Any idea would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your master template (the part that includes css) to your question?

Comment: Sure. I am using bootstrap 3. These are what I am using in the master template  :                                                          <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have defined all your include paths **relative**. So when the directory level in the URL changes the styles don't get found. You should use the helpers Laravel provides to generate a full URL.

There's [`asset()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or even a helper to create the full `link` tag for including

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

(And there's one for javascript files too)

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/script.js') }}
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you very much lukasgeiter!