# I lose my bootstrap styles when passing variable (get) to route->Controller->View in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I lose my bootstrap styles when passing variable (get) to route->Controller->View in Laravel 5.4.
here is my code-

```
header.blade.php->
<a href="{{URL::to( '/news/'.$v_all_published_category->id )}}">

    web.php->
    Route::get('/news/{id}', 'NewsController@view_news');

    NewsController.php->
    public function view_news($id) {
            $category_info = Category::where('publication_status', 1)->get();
            $category_product = Product::where('id', $id)->get();
            $data = array();
            $data['header_content'] = view('Front_End.includes.header', ['all_published_category' => $category_info]);
            $data['home_slider']= view('Front_End.slider.home_slider');
            $data['main_content'] = view('Front_End.category.category_content', ['category_product' => $category_product]);
            $data['footer_content']= view('Front_End.includes.footer');
            return view('Front_End.master')->with($data);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

@EdwardPalen

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NewsFeed</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/animate.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/font.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/li-scroller.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/slick.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/theme.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('page_assets/assets/css/style.css')}}">

    </head>
    <body>

        <a class="scrollToTop" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
        <div class="container">

            @yield('header_content')

            @yield('slider')

            @yield('main_content')

            @yield('footer_content')
        </div>
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/wow.min.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/bootstrap.min.jss') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.min.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_assets/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js') }}
        {{ Html::script('page_asset`enter code here`s/assets/js/custom.js') }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the blade helper tags?

When the directory level in the URL changes the styles don't get found. You should use the helpers Laravel provides to generate a full URL.

Try to integrate it like this in the app.blade.php file:

There's `assets()`

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or even a helper to create the full link tag for including:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

(And there's one for javascript files too)

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/script.js') }}
```

You can take as reference of this issue in this link:

[I lose my bootstrap styles when passing variable (get) to route->Controller->View in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473626/i-lose-my-bootstrap-styles-when-passing-variable-get-to-route-controller-vie)

Comment: Thanks.. your suggestion solved half of the problem.. now the css works but javascript isnt working.                                                            my composer.jsn file includes "laravelcollective/html":"5.4.*", aliases includes form and html facade. providers includes Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, i can't understand why its not working?

Comment: Okay, you can show the file where you are referencing your css and js files.

Comment: Please see the next answer

Comment: Ok, try putting it this way {{ asset('page_assets/assets/js/jquery.min.js') }} and the other links.

Comment: If you're using Form or HTML helpers, you will see an error stating class 'Form' not found or  class 'Html' not found. The Form and HTML helpers have been deprecated in Laravel 5.0; however, there are community-driven replacements such as those maintained by the Laravel Collective. [You can check the documentation for more detail here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

A solution and method that I use frequently.

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can include CSS and JS files, and you can put them directly in the public / css or public / js folder and then link them from the layout with the asset () function: